# Creating smoke domain manually instead of using quick smoke makes domain visible

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

When I use quick smoke to create a smoke simulation everything works fine,

[image]

but when I create a box and make it a domain, the smoke simulation is not visible in the render due to visible domain?

[image]

What's causing this?

Comment: Please make your question clearer.  Please show the settings for the manual domain.  A domain can remain a box before the simulation starts.

Comment: In the past there was problem with having more than one domain with a bake.

Comment: Only one domain in the scene at a time, domain settings default... when I make a box a domain manually it just doesn't show the smoke in the render

Comment: You have not yet shown your settings.  Screen Capture.  You might even have an extra box.  Did you Bake?

Comment: What material have you assigned to the domain? Is it a volumetric or just a surface shader? The Quick Smoke does more than just create the domain - it also assigns a volumetric material to it.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the default material for the domain is still enabled [image]
so you see on that image that it doesn't work[image]
so you have to make a random image and apply quick smoke on it and then delete it and then select the domain again and choose the smoke domain material [image]  and then it works.[image]